# Application log not writing logs in JBOSS 7.2 AS server

Tags: jboss, log4j

I have deployed my application on JBOSS7.2. It is working fine on some servers. But on some servers, application log is not working. It just creates the file and  writes "successfully created memcache client
" and nothing else is logged. The same build in working fine on some JBOSS 7 servers. Tried whatever is written on internet, not helping.

Answer (score 0):

could be a problem with your:

- logging-configuration
- the general logging level

Which log level are you using in your application?

Regards,
Sascha